# Photoshop: Strange defaults for layer styles

Tags: adobe-photoshop, windows

Photoshop layer styles now have strange defaults on my system, seems like all values are scaled up. I don't know when or how it has happened.

Eg:

> - Bevel size: 84px
> - Stroke size: 52px
> - Inner shadow distance, size: 84px
> - Inner glow size: 84px
> - Drop shadow distance, size: 84px ...

`reset to default` also brings these values. I don't yet have a chance to re-install.

I can always use `Make Default` and rewrite each value but I don't prefer this because:

1. I don't exactly know each value on a new installation, and I want to have factory defaults for each value to have a smooth experience across different installations
2. There may be other anomalies due to a potential resolution / scale value hidden somewhere, which also may be the source of the problem

Does anybody know where Photoshop keeps these defaults, in registry or an xml file?

`Photoshop CS6` `Windows 7 x64`

Comment: Have you tried dumping the preferences file? I know for CS3 on windows 7 there is `C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS3\Adobe Photoshop CS3 Settings\Adobe Photoshop CS3 Prefs.psp` Maybe there is a similar file. Try moving it to another directory and then restart photoshop and see if that helps.

Comment: @ckpepper02 thank you. I found the equivalent file, but this didn't work for the default style settings. I'll try some other files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try holding [Ctrl] + [Alt] + [Shift] right after opening PS. (RIGHT after you click the icon)

If that doesn't work, there's a full reference here: 
http://forums.adobe.com/message/4209421

Comment: Thank you! This time I switched to another system, but I'll try that the next time.